# Texture/Color showing up in viewpoint but not in render?

Tags: color

[image]

This is what I see in my viewpoint, I set the texture to the texture file I want to use, the color for the texture should already be set, but isn't appearing, so I set it to the brown texture I want. UV was unwrapped.
This is what I see when I render.
[image]

Not sure why this is happening? I'm a new user, so please explain why it happens!!

Thank you!

Comment: I don’t know how you’re doing the texture on the table, but if you’ll notice in the material panel, the actual rendering material color is yellow. You can see it clearly in your screenshot.

Comment: Secondly, if a solid color is all you want, you DO NOT need an image texture. Just change the said yellow material color to the desired color.